# summaries extracted from data frame info

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

```
data <- 
STUDY ID  BASE  CYCLE1   DIED  PROG
  1    1    100    30     No    Yes
  1    2    NA     20     Yes   No
  1    3    16     NA     Yes   Yes 
  1    4    15     10     Yes   Yes
```

I wanted to make a summary of the following:

1. how many subjects have both baseline and CYCLE1 value?
2. Of those in 1, how many had DIED?
3. Of those in 1, how many had DIED or PROG?

Answers:

1. 2-subjects (50% of subjects) ==> subjects 1 & 4
2. 1-subject (25%) ===> this is subject 4
3. 2-subjects (50%) ==> subjectys 1 & 4

A summary table by STUDY for this would be great (showing the number and percentage).
I am using Rstudio.

Comment: It is. not clear how many columns you need in the output

Comment: @akrun looking to have number of subjects and %. for example, for Question 1 there are 2 subjects out of the 4 subjects, so an output like this `2 (50%) would be best.

Comment: I showed a ssolution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is based on the first `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data %>%
   group_by(STUDY) %>%
   filter(!is.na(BASE) & !is.na(CYCLE1)) %>%
   summarise(ID = str_c(ID, collapse=", "), 
             n1 = n(),
             n2 = sum(DIED== "Yes"), 
             n3 = sum(DIED == "Yes"|PROG == "Yes"))
# A tibble: 1 x 5
#  STUDY ID       n1    n2    n3
#  <int> <chr> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1 1, 4      2     1     2
```

---

if we need the percentage as well

```
out <- data %>% 
        group_by(STUDY) %>%
        mutate(i1 = !is.na(BASE) & !is.na(CYCLE1),
          perc1 = 100 * mean(i1), 
          n1 = sum(i1), 
          i2 = DIED == "Yes" & i1, 
          perc2 = 100 * mean(i2),
          n2 = sum(i2), 
          i3 = (DIED == "Yes"|PROG == "Yes") & i1, 
          perc3 = 100 * mean(i3), 
          n3 = sum(i3)) %>%
        filter(i1) %>% 
        select(STUDY, ID, matches("perc"), matches("n")) %>% 
        mutate(ID = toString(ID)) %>% 
        slice(1)
# A tibble: 1 x 8
# Groups:   STUDY [1]
#  STUDY ID    perc1 perc2 perc3    n1    n2    n3
#  <int> <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <int> <int>
#1     1 1, 4     50    25    50     2     1     2
```

It can be further modified to format the output

```
library(tidyr) # 0.8.3.9000
out %>% 
   pivot_longer(cols = perc1:n3, names_to = c( "perc", "n"), 
            names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])") %>%
   group_by(STUDY, ID, n) %>%
   summarise(value = sprintf("%d (%d%%)", last(value), first(value))) %>% 
   select(-n)
```